# Can't get HTML snippet to work in existing email template

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template, html

I'm trying to add a footer to an existing email template using the HTML block. I would assume that the DOCTYPE, HTML, HEAD, BODY tags and CSS are already there. If so, I should be able to able to add style tags and my divs in the HTML edit section, but this doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have a video or instructions they can point me to?

Here is an example.

```
<style>

section-5 {
height: 1054px;
width: 600px;
background: transparent url('/images/myimage.svg') 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
opacity: 1;
}

</style>

<div class="section-5">
        
        <div class="footer-background">
            <div class="footer-logo">
                
            </div>

            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="https://www.myurl.com" target="_blank" class="footer-title">MERCHANDISE</a>
                            <div class="footer-divider-image"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="https://www.myurl.com" target="_blank" class="footer-title">FAQS</a>
                            <div class="footer-divider-image"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="https://www.myurl.com" target="_blank" class="footer-title">WHERE TO BUY</a>
                            <div class="footer-divider-image"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="https://www.myurl.com" target="_blank" class="footer-title">Sign Up</a>
                            <div class="footer-divider-image"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="https://www.myurl.com" target="_blank" class="footer-title">My Stuff&trade;</a>
                            <div class="footer-divider-image"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="footer-title-admin">
                        <td>
                            <a href="https://www.myurl.com" target="_blank">
                                <span>CONTACT US&nbsp;</span>
                            <a />
                            <a href="https://www.myurl.com" target="_blank">
                                <span>&nbsp;TERMS AND CONDITIONS&nbsp;</span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="https://www.myurl.com" target="_blank">
                                <span>&nbsp;PRIVACY POLICY</span>
                            </a>
                            <div class="footer-divider-image"></div>
                         </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="follow-us">
                    FOLLOW US
                </div>
                <div class="social-icons">
                    <center>
                        <span><a href='https://wwww.instagram.com' target="_blank"><img src='~/images/instagram_icon.png' /></a></span>
                        <span><a href='https://wwww.facebook.com' target="_blank"><img src='~/images/facebook_icon.png' /></a></span>
                        <span><a href='https://wwww.pinterest.com' target="_blank"><img src='~/images/pinterest_icon.png' /></a></span>
                        <span><a href='https://wwww.youtube.com' target="_blank"><img src='~/images/youtube_icon.png' /></a></span>
                    </center>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-language">
                    <p>
                        PARA 1
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        PARA 2
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the exact problem? Have you tried using in-line styling?

Comment: Not that I think that's the reason of your problem, but you want to correct the "< a/>" tag after CONTACT US.

Comment: @zuzannamj What do you mean by in-line? Are you talking about style="" inside all the divs?

Comment: @FelixvanHove Good catch!

Comment: @zuzannamj Nothing renders. There is no HTML displayed on the page.